# Constructing Dictionary - List not same length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if it possible to create a dictionary and convert it into a Pandas dataframe where each dictionary key has an array of values, but the array will vary in length.

e.g. `col3` only has 2 values and all other lists have 3 values. Can I somehow put `NaN` to "fill" in the missing values and not get an error?

```
col1 = ["Bottom", "sss", "ddd"]
col2 = ["boo", "sss", "foo"]
col3 = [999, 89]

d = {"Type": col1, "Style": col2, "Profit": col3}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing with

```
df=pd.DataFrame([col1,col2,col3],index=['T','S','P']).T
df
Out[165]: 
        T    S     P
0  Bottom  boo   999
1     sss  sss    89
2     ddd  foo  None
```

Another option

```
pd.Series(d).apply(pd.Series).T
Out[174]: 
     Type Style Profit
0  Bottom   boo    999
1     sss   sss     89
2     ddd   foo    NaN
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to turn series `P` to dtype `float`?

Comment: @jpp I do not think so , since this result by the `T`.

Comment: @jpp Once you have the dataframe constructed, you can call `.astype(np.float)` on the series you wish to convert.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary isn't strictly required. Using [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(col1, col2, col3)),
                  columns=['Type', 'Style', 'Profit'])

print(df)

     Type Style  Profit
0  Bottom   boo   999.0
1     sss   sss    89.0
2     ddd   foo     NaN
```

Notice the [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor is smart enough to convert numeric series to numeric, even though each tuple in the input list of tuples contains mixed types.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - you can fill the missing values with `numpy.nan`:

```
import numpy as np

col1 = ["Bottom", "sss", "ddd"]
col2 = ["boo", "sss", "foo"]
col3 = [999, 89, np.nan]

d = {"Type": col1, "Style": col2, "Profit": col3}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
```

**Output**

```
   Profit Style    Type
0   999.0   boo  Bottom
1    89.0   sss     sss
2     NaN   foo     ddd
```

Comment: This is nice, but a bit manual. How do you suggest OP can automatically add the required number of `np.nan` values to each input list?

Comment: There's not an obvious way with the information we're given - we don't know which list is the longest, or where the `NaN`s should be, etc.  I mostly posted this method to show OP that the `np.nan` datatype is what he's after.